# How to programmatically edit a field?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a type node called flat, a field called latitude. I want to update the value of this field in a module each time the node is updated.

I try to use the hook_node_update() but nothing happens :

```
function flat_node_update($node){
    print_r($node);  
    return $node;
}
```

Do you have the answer?

Comment: [hook_node_update()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) should not return any value; changing the values of the fields in `$node`, and then returning the modified object doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

hook_node_update() is called *after* the node has been updated.

You want [hook_node_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) instead. If the nid is not empty, it is an update.

Comment: But just for a test, I try to print 'hello', and nothing happen with these functions. It's like my hook are not called.

Comment: Use drupal_set_message() or dpm() for debugging, not print. Did you clear the cache after you added your hook implementation?

Comment: Is the function in a module called "flat"?  In the case above the module file would be called flat.module and would be in a directory called module which is enabled. If nothing is being echoed to the screen at all this may be the reason.